# XOM: is Builder.build() thread safe?

Tags: java, xml, thread-safety, xom

Is Builder.build() thread safe? I couldn't find any info in XOM Javadoc.

Comment: Not sure, but the slide at http://www.xom.nu/whatswrong/img23.html says (in a very general way) "Not thread safe".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Builder` doesn't tell us that one of the builder methods is thread-safe and we have no reason to assume it: the methods are not synchronized (look at the code) and the class uses the first available parser and delegates the work.

So we should avoid sharing one instance of `nu.xom.Builder` between different threads.